# COPY command: AWS Aurora Postgresql, s3 extension

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to execute a COPY command to import csv file from S3 (result of UNLOAD command from Redshift) into an Amazon Aurora database [Using the aws_s3.table_import_from_s3 Function to Import Amazon S3 Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Migrating.html#USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.FileFormats), but I don't know to indicate the quotes character in the command.

```
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
   'hr.person', 
    '',
    '(FORMAT CSV,HEADER true,QUOTES ''"'')',
   aws_commons.create_s3_uri('redshift-unload-tmp','resul_file.csv','us-east-2')
);
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the difficulty being caused by the format parameter being enclosed in single quotes, and also having to use singles quotes _within_ the `QUOTES` parameter? Does the format you show work? Or perhaps using `QUOTES \'"\'`?

Comment: John, thank you, I fixed it, If you are using CSV format, it uses quotes " by default, then I don't need to indicate QUOTE option.

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain my use case more detailed:

**Source** 
I used the UNLOAD command to "export" data from a table in Redshift, this is the command:

```
UNLOAD('SELECT * FROM schema.table')
TO 's3://bucket-name/prefix_'
HEADER
CSV
NULL AS '\000'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::accountNumber:role/aRoleWithRedshiftAndS3Permissions';
```

**Target**
I need to put the Redshift data (now file in s3) into RDS database (Aurora-postgresql), before import file, I did a rename of the files in s3 and add the extension .csv; I used pgAdmin 4 as a Postgresql client, and open a query editor to execute the following commands:

1. Add new s3 extension to the database:

```html
CREATE EXTENSION aws_s3 CASCADE;
NOTICE: installing required extension "aws_commons"
```

2. Execute function to import file from s3

```html
select aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
 'schame.table_name',
 '',
 '(FORMAT CSV, HEADER true)',
 aws_commons.create_s3_uri('sample_s3_bucket_name','source_file_name.csv','aws-region')
);
```

**Note:** If you use CSV format by default quote character is ", then you don't need to indicate the quote as an option parameter, you need to do if you are using a different quote character.